# How to add events for angular js bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I would like to add onclick event for angular js bar chart and get Y-axis value . how to achieve this below is my code

```
 <div ng-controller="BarCtrl" class="chart_contr" style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;margin-top: 10%;width: 300px;padding:0px 10px;">
         <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="data" labels="labels" width="400" height="400"></canvas> 
                            </div>
```

javascript

```
 app.controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

  $scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];
  });
```

Comment: So the bar chart is going in the `<canvas>` element? What are you actually using to create the bar chart? That library may expose functions to make what you want easily, but there's not enough info currently here to tell you how to do what you want.

Comment: I am using angular.js
angular-chart.js
Chart.min.js
widget-controller.js
ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `click="onClick"` (not `ng-click`) attribute to your `<canvas>`

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="data" labels="labels" width="400" height="400" click="onClick"></canvas>
```

Add this to your controller:

```
  $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
    console.log(points[0].value); // 0 -> Series A, 1 -> Series B
  };
```

Comment: I have tried what u have suggested, onclick event is wokring but I am not getting correct values while clicking on the bar chart. I have added points like [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40] and I am accessing like points[0].y I am getting values while clicking like 75.2,90.4,37.3,34.7,98.0,100,59,138.5. I dont understand what are these values

Comment: @Shabarinath Looks like `.y` gives you the current point of your mouse and `.value` will give you the bar chart value for the bar you clicked. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access $event in the ng-click so then i think you should be able to use getY()

Comment: Didn't get you can u add your answer in detail?